# WSUIPA package options?

Tags: fonts, xetex, symbols, sans-serif

Is there a package that contains the IPA fonts in SANS-Serif mode?

[WSUIPA](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wsuipa) is the most extensive package I see, but the fonts are serif. I would like a sans serif version, especially for the character positions 25 (I use it for a symbol for an event from where some deductions may be made), 27 (for experiment, an event created with an objective), 75 (symbol for a causality relation between two events) and 101 (as a shorthand for "for a particular"). I have been taking these symbols from a font called quivira as well as some other symbols of armenian and runic font plane. Recently after coming across the WSUIPA package, I see some of them already have a LaTeX command.

But I don't find one with the fonts in sans serif. Does such a possibility exists?

Comment: Wouldn't `tipa` suit you better?

Comment: i see the manual thereof, and it is also serif - in case i missed the sans serif version of tipa, please guide me

Comment: I'm afraid there's no sans serif IPA font available; the reference to `tipa` is just to a more recent and maintained package.

Comment: the only sans ipa font, that i can see, is from sil (summer institute of linguistics).  afaict it's an otf font, so you would need to work in `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: wonderful, thank you, i will go and test SIL.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments